# setting ckeditor on textarea in php blog

Tags: html, ckeditor

I can't set my CKEditor in my blog

***THE HTML***

```
<textarea id="body" name="body" class="col-md-12" rows="5"></textarea>
```

***JavaScript***

```
<script>
    ClassicEditor
        .create(document.querySelector('#editor'), {})
        .catch(error => {
           console.log(error);
    });
</script>
```

and thank you
I am sorry for my bad English

Comment: change your `textarea` id to `editor` instead of `body`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just type your `teaxtarea` id by wrong you need to change it to `editor` instead

```js
ClassicEditor
   .create(document.querySelector('#editor'), {})
   .catch(error => {
       console.log(error);
   });
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/24.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
 <textarea id="editor" name="body" class="col-md-12" rows="5"></textarea>
```

for more info check this [quick example](https://cdn.ckeditor.com/)

Comment: run the code snippet in the answer and it works fine, you could take the code in the snippet above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226725/discussion-between-joseph-and-mij3as).